# How to write a JDO Query to sort result based on long attribute?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, jdoql

I want to write a JDO query which fetches all objects of Advertisement class and then sort it on the base of time attribute of type long. For fetching all Advertisement objects, i am using following query.

```
 List<Advertisement> annonces = null;
 Query query = pm.newQuery(Advertisement.class);
 advertisements = (List<Advertisement>) query.execute();
```

I want to add a filter which should sort result on the base of long property of Advertisement class. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This Query solved my problem:

```
 Query query = pm.newQuery(Annonce.class);
 query.setOrdering("timeOfAdvertisement desc");
 annonces = (List<Annonce>) query.execute();
```